# Czech language input method and font support in gvim 7.4 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, gvim, unicode

I would like to reopen a question related to the following:

[(Czech) character set support in gvim 7.3 on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/653914/czech-character-set-support-in-gvim-7-3-on-windows-7)

Basically, in that post I noticed that some Czech characters
were being displayed as black squares. So I posted the question
and noticed that the problem seemed to go away by changing the
font. I thought that solved the problem because the characters
in the file I was using displayed correctly.

However, I have noticed the following: while some Czech characters
display correctly by changing the font from the Gvim menu, others
do not display correctly:

For instance when I paste the character Ů (Latin capital letter u with ring above)
or ů (Latin small letter u with ring above), no font displays the resulting character
correctly. For instance, the *Fixedsys* font displays a black square and a small u,
respectively, while *Lucida Console* displays a capital U and a small U, respectively.
I have tried all fonts available from the gvim drop-down menu, and none seem to work
for this particular case.

The problem does not end here. The input method for unicode characters
produces the wrong characters:

**CTRL-V u0160** should produce the Czech character (Š) but the backquote (') is inserted instead.
**CTRL-V u016e** should produce the Czech character (Ů) but the n character (n) is inserted instead.
And the list goes on.

As if that were not enough, there is a list of alternative input method key combinations
at the following site (which is a list of digraphs):
http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/doc/digraph.txt

but despite having the latest verion of gvim, when I type ":digraphs", this list does
not show up. Only the old list from gvim 7.3 shows up, which does not include these.

For instance CTRL-K U0 and CTRL-K u0 both produce the character zero **instead** of the following:

> Ů U0 016E 0366 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE
>
> ů u0 016F 0367 LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH RING ABOVE

To summarize, despite gvim 7.4 being recently released, none of the distributed
fonts are compatible with the Czech language, inserting unicode via CTRL-V
seems to produce the wrong characters, and digraph support is incomplete.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that coding Latin-2 (iso-8859-2) and Windows-1250 (used by windows) differ in some characters:

```
ž, š, ť, Ž, Š, Ť
```

All differences are summarized [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) or [Czech version](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)

If you set `encoding=cp1250`, then it'll be ok.

---

I don't want to prolong comments so I'm adding that here.

There is a problem that standard code page uses only `1byte` (hex 100) for characters, so there are ISO standards for different languages.
If you have `set encoding iso-8859-2` and trying to add unicode character (hex 160) `Š`, than gvim loops over to character (hex 60). You have to use codes ISO-8859-2, where `Š` ìs (hex 089). Other codes here: http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2

UTF-8 on the other hand uses `2bytes` and contains simultaineously all? letters and signs. So if you use `set encoding=utf-8` and then add `U0160` or `U5927` you'll get `Š` resp. `大`.

`Fixedsys` contains ů and Ů, OR there is a difference in font versions between Windows language mutations (I use Czech version), but I doubt that. You can use windows utility `Charmap.exe`, there you can select desired font and check which characters it supports, even their unicode code.

I was trying briefly some of default fonts in GVim and there seems to be some that supports Chinese (ie `MS Mincho`), but I don't which signs are important.

GVim seems to be supporting only `monospace` character fonts so, if you'll be searching for another font be aware of that. :)

Comment: OK. That solved all of the above problems (on Windows7) from the following point of view: now I can :set encoding cp1250 and I can enter all of the Czech characters with either of the CTRL-K (digraph) or the CTRL-V (unicode codes) methods.

Comment: Of course, when I create the CodePage 1250 file under Windows 7 and then transfer it to a Linux environment and open it there using LibreOffice Writer, (e.g. using the /usr/bin/lowriter command), a dialog box show up where I can choose the "Character Set", and I need to specify "Eastern Europe (Windows-1250/WinLatin 2), otherwise the wrong character set will be loaded and wrong stuff would be displayed in place of the special characters.

Comment: From my point of view, however, what is even better is to set the encoding to utf-8 with the command :set encoding=utf-8 under windows 7, edit the file, then save it, and then open it under Linux where the default character set is utf-8 rather than uso 8859-1 latin1, and open it there under Linux without having to specify any flags. Regards.

Comment: So, since the default encoding is latin1, and utf-8 is the most portable of all file formats, rather than using a Windows-specific file format such as a specific code page, it is perhaps better to :set encoding=utf-8 inside the _vimrc (or .vimrc). The only problem that remains is how to ensure the default font setting supporting the desired characters is saved as a user preference.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with default font with utf-8, `Fixedsys` supports czech script.

Comment: No, on my Windows 7 system with Gvim 7.4 installed the font family FixedSys does not support Czech script. For instance when I enter the Czech character Ů Gvim displays a filled square. This happens both when I :set encoding=cp1250 as well as when I :set encoding=utf-8 prior to entering the character. I've had to switch to Lucida Console for Czech to be displayed correctly. Lucida Console works with both files based on the utf-8 encoding as well as files based on the cp1250 encoding.

Comment: Also, as an aside, neither the FixedSys font nor the Lucida Console font can display Chinese characters. With UTF-8 selected I tried the FangSong font, which properly displays Chinese encoded UTF-8 characters, but with this font Czech characters cannot be displayed.

Comment: I would like to be able to use a font which supports both Latin1 script, Latin2 script, and Chinese script, on Gvim, all at the same time, with all of these scripts encoded in a compatible manner, i.e. in UTF-8 for instance. But I cannot find such a font. :-(

Comment: Would have been better if Gvim came with its own font supporting all the characters of all languages of the world using UTF-8 encoding. But it seems it doesn't.