# encoding that is compatible with both latin1 and uft-8?

Tags: windows, vim, encoding

I use vim to edit files and I can make it display Korean only if I set the "Current language for non-Unicode program" to "Korean". I can accept that thtat is the way it supposed to be. But then if I type/copy any latin characters with accent mark, things break. Is it possible to encode a text file with both latin and korean chracters?

Comment: This answer should be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/668720/czech-language-input-method-and-font-support-in-gvim-7-4-on-windows-7/668725#668725

Comment: In short the recommendation is to use `fixedsys`. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hm.. No.. In short use UTF-8..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a non-Unicode environment, what characters can be represented is determined by the encoding. Unless you can set a general Unicode encoding (which I don't think is possible on Windows) that can represent both, this is not possible, it's either Korean or extended Latin characters.

I'm assuming this is Vim in the Windows console; it should work with GVIM (and `:set encoding=utf-8`).

Comment: Yes, the encoding is already utf-8. I believe there is a conflict between the the character set for special Latin characters and Korean font, so if I use "Character Map" software that comes with Windows, I can type extended Latin characters. There are online converters like [this one](rishida.net/tools/conversion), but I found Windows Powershell to be a practical tool,

    `PS C:\> gc -en utf8 in.txt | Out-File -en ascii out.txt`

as denoted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets)